# api response getting with simple php file but not getting response in codeigniter loop

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

**api response getting with simple php file but not getting response in codeigniter loop**

working properly in simple php file, but not working in codeigniter loop.. **even with same parameters**

**simple php file code (getting response):**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.easyship.com/rate/v1/rates");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"origin_country_alpha2\": \"US\",
  \"origin_postal_code\": \"10001\",
  \"destination_country_alpha2\": \"US\",
  \"destination_postal_code\": \"01032\",
  \"taxes_duties_paid_by\": \"Sender\",
  \"is_insured\": false,
  \"items\": [
    {
      \"actual_weight\": 8,
      \"height\": 8,
      \"width\": 2.1,
      \"length\": 2.8,
      \"category\": \"health_beauty\",
      \"declared_currency\": \"SGD\",
      \"declared_customs_value\": 100
    }
  ]
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

**codeigniter file code (code fine, but not getting response):**

```
foreach($this->data['crtres'] as $crs){

   $prodqry="SELECT * FROM `ci_products` WHERE `prod_id`='".$crs->product_id."'";
   $prodres=$this->home->customQuery($prodqry);

   $prodcatqry="SELECT * FROM `ci_prod_categories` WHERE `prod_cat_id`='".$prodres[0]->prod_cat_id."'";
   $prodcatres=$this->home->customQuery($prodcatqry);

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.easyship.com/rate/v1/rates");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

   switch($prodcatres[0]->prod_cat_name) {
       case 'Home':
       $espc = 'home_appliances';
       break;

       case 'Beauty':
       $espc = 'health_beauty';
       break;    

       default:
       $espc = 'others';
       break;
   }

   $optString = '{
     \"origin_country_alpha2\": \"US\",
     \"origin_postal_code\": \"10001\",
     \"destination_country_alpha2\": \"US\",
     \"destination_postal_code\": \"'.$this->input->post('shipping_zipcode').'\",
     \"taxes_duties_paid_by\": \"Sender\",
     \"is_insured\": false,
     \"items\": [
     {
          \"actual_weight\": '.$prodres[0]->prod_weight.',
          \"height\": '.$prodres[0]->prod_height.',
          \"width\": '.$prodres[0]->prod_width.',
          \"length\": '.$prodres[0]->prod_length.',
          \"category\": \"'.$espc.'\",
          \"declared_currency\": \"USD\",
          \"declared_customs_value\": '.$crs->product_quantity.'
      }
     ]
    }';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $optString);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>"
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($response);

    $ratesDetArr = $response->rates;

    $shiptot += $ratesDetArr[0]->total_charge;   
}
```

please suggest me changes

what is difference in both, please give me idea to solve this issue

Comment: exchange your `\"` width `"` - e.g. `$optString = '{"origin_country_alpha2":...}';`

Comment: **Stop** assembling JSON manually … Create the appropriate _data structure_, and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: _“what is difference in both”_ - the string delimiters that where used. _“please give me idea to solve this issue”_ - please go read up on _basics of the syntax_ … https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php